# UR5 Communication C-API

Tags: ros, communication, ros-industrial, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Community,

i try to connect the UR5- Universal Roboter with the C-API. But i think there is no current example how it works.
Can anyone explain me how it works?

1.Questions:

1. How can i compile the Sample - Code?
2. How can i Transfer the C-Code to the UR5?
3. How can i Programm the UR5 without any documentation for it?
4. Does anyone have some samples for me?

Thank you for your help.

Greetings.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208144/ur5-communication-c-api/) by [SakulRelda](https://answers.ros.org/users/22295/sakulrelda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi SakulRelda,

just have a look to the github-repository [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot) and the C-API-documentation [here](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/src/doc/move_group_interface_tutorial.html). Insert `"manipulator"`instead of `"right_arm"`. Compiling works using the command `catkin_make` in the command line. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace).

Using all that you'll be able to use the UR5 through C-API.

Best regards

---

Originally posted by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) with karma: 236 on 2015-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-29**:
Note that the C-API driver is only compatible with system versions up to 1.8 on CB2 controllers. CB3 controllers are **not** supported (see also [wiki/ur_c_api_bringup](http://wiki.ros.org/ur_c_api_bringup)).